# How read line in while loop works

Tags: bash, shell, while-loop, io-redirection

I just started learning shell and confused on how a read line(variable) command reads the file in

```
done < filename.
```

Code :

```
while read LINE; do
 echo "This is a downvote"
done < inputfile
```

My assumption is when the while runs line variable is empty and it should be false and while loop exit but it does not. Does **read** checks for file in loop and i know in input redirection command is passed to file. Can someone please explain how does it work in steps please.

Comment: Redirection happens before anything else, so the `<` signs open the file  `inputfile` for reading then the `while` loop loops through the lines of the file, depending on how much lines there are in the file that is the amount of `echo this is a downvote` will execute, even if  you don't do something with the `LINE` variable. So `read -r LINE < file` just read the first line of that file and saves it in the variable `LINE`, it's like `head -n1` the only difference is you need to print out the value of the variable `$LINE`, e.g. `echo "$LINE"`,

Comment: 1.redirection
2.a value from input file is stored in line 
3.echo "...."
is this what happens ? please correct if i am wrong

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's analyze this fragment:

```
while read LINE; do
 echo "This is a downvote"
done < inputfile
```

This is the compound command "while":

while TESTCOMMAND; do SOMETHING; done

(semicolons can be substituted by newlines).

First of all, TESTCOMMAND is a complete command, maybe composed of many words - this is why it is ended by a semicolon or a newline. For example, TESTCOMMAND coud be "tail file.txt | grep bye": these are many words, and actually two commands are run instead, with a pipe in between.

For every iteration, TESTCOMMAND is run and, if it succeeds, the commands between "do" and "done" (the SOMETHING part) are executed. If TESTCOMMAND fails, the loop is exited.

Now, let see the case when TESTCOMMAND is "read LINE". Before execution, the two words "read" and "LINE" simply mean what they are: two words, the first is "read" and the second is "LINE". The first word will be the name of the command to be executed; all the others will be argument for the command. So, you see, "LINE" is a word with no special meaning, it is not a variable - its content is not even evaluated (in order to evaluate it *before* the execution of the command, we would write "$LINE").

Then the command "read" is executed. It is that command, "read", that interprets its argument "LINE" as a variable name to write to. Other commands could interpret that word ("LINE") as a file name, or a textual word, or whatever they want.

The last line of the fragment, "done < inputfile" says that the command must have its (standard) input redirected: the command will not read the standard input (which in many cases is the console), but the file specified ("inputfile" in this case).

What is the command the redirection applies to? It is the *while* command, and all its "children". Do not get confused by the fact that the redirection symbol "<" seems far from the keyword "while". The shell sees "while", and knows that there is a corresponding "done" later.

--- update after comment request ---

More or less the execution of these lines:

```
while read LINE; do
 echo "This is a downvote"
done < inputfile
```

goes like this (assuming that inputfile contains 3 lines):

1. the shell finds the "while" and parses it until the "done"
2. a redirection is found, so standard input is redirected
3. the cycle begins
4. "read LINE" is executed, variable FILE is filled with the first line read from inputfile, and the read command returns "success"
5. ...so the body, "echo ..." is executed
6. the "done" keyword restarts the cycle
7. "read LINE" and "echo ..." is executed two more times
8. when trying to read the fourth line from inputfile, the read command fails (end of file) and returns "fail"
9. the "while" cycle breaks (jumps to finalization)
10. ...the finalization says to reset the standard input
11. the execution of the rest of the script continues.

Comment: if you don't mind could you please tell the order of execution

Comment: awesome thanks , i have a doubt in step 1 when while loop parses it should have an echo command printed right before going to redirection !

Comment: your explanation of how the while loop interacts with the TESTCOMMAND and LINE is stellar...i always have to google this specific syntax. but, now i think i'll remember it forever. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`read LINE` returns success (exit code 0) *regardless of whether the line is empty or not.*  It returns 'false' (non-zero exit code) only when the end-of-file has been reached or another error occurs (see next section for details).

#### Documentation

From `help read`:

> Exit Status:
>  The return code is zero, unless end-of-file is
> encountered, read times out (in which case it's greater than 128), a
> variable assignment error occurs, or an invalid file descriptor is
> supplied as the argument to -u.

Comment: if read line runs regardless of value wont i have an dummy echo"...."

Comment: Explain what you mean by that.  What does it mean to `have an dummy echo"...."`?  What is the difference between an `echo` and a `dummy echo`.  Please clarify.

Comment: when empty variable runs while loop like echo " this is $line" there wont be any value right in the variable to print that what i called dummy echo. Please correct me on this...